# form submit after click unfriend button in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In my project I add some javascript to avoid user click button many times. There is one page where it fetches data from the registration page. Each data row I put `add` and `unfriend` button (disabled). Once user clicks `add`, the prompt box appears to ask the user to enter subject and click `ok`. After clicking `ok`, the `unfriend` button will be able to click. Here my problem is once click `add` button the prompt appear and after click `ok` the data does not insert into database. If I click `unfriend` button it inserts into database. I want the data submitted whenever user clicks the `add` button. I think it's because this form has two submit buttons but I don't know how to distinguish the buttons. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>My Resuming</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
   </head>     
   <script>
      function myFunction(form){
         var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
         if (subject != null){
           form['subject'].value= subject;
           form['btn'].disabled=false;
           form['add'].disabled=true;
           form['add'].value="request sent";
           return false;
           form.submit();
         }

         form['add'].disabled = false;
         form['btn'].disabled = true;
         form['add'].value = "Add friend";
         return true;
      }
   </script>
<body>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {      
        $register_ID=$row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $gender = $row['gender'];
        $main_subject = $row["main_subject"];
        $subject_add = $row["subject_add"];
        $rate_main = $row["rate_main"];
        $rate_add = $row["rate_add"];
        $qualification = $row["qualification"];
        ?>

                <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="btn" disabled />
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['sid'] ;?>/>
                        <input type="submit" onclick="return myFunction(this.form);" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="add" class="btn" value="add"  />
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    }
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['subject']) and $_POST['id']) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['sid'];
    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];
    $status = "yes";
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,subject,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$subject','$friend_id') ";

    if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
        $_SESSION['status']="yes";
        $_SESSION['friend_id']=$friend_id;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    } else {
    }
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed your tabbing which reveals a lot of invalid html. You have half a table, an extra close form tag (`</form>`), your javascript function returns `false` before you submit the form, etc...

Comment: @Rasclatt Too Broad?

Comment: Also all your form ids are the same, you  can not have the same id name if you are trying to interact via `id` name. I don't think you are in this example, so that is for the future.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's just riddled with basic errors that need to be addressed, so too broad or *"Why is my code not working?"* might be the fate of this one.

Comment: @Rasclatt i put two forms...i never paste here that form,thats y got two form closing.

Comment: @mickmackusa i never put prepare statement because this one just for trial..

Comment: I wouldn't have a form inside of another form (at least thats what it looks like).

Comment: Also, trial or no trial, you should just be doing prepared statements.